# WordPress localization

Tags: l10n

In WordPress localization files (.po), does php map files by the line number eg. `comments.php:60` or msgid `msgid "<span class=\"meta-nav\">&larr;</span> Older Comments"`.

So basically, if I have said string in comments.php in line 60, and move it to line 74, does it still get localized by the msgid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if I have said string in comments.php
>   in line 60, and move it to line 74,
>   does it still get localized by the
>   msgid?

Yes it does. Localization does not depend on line numbers of strings.